# Is it possible to reduce function to one single line?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ends-with

I wrote an image checker, now I wonder how can I reduce the number of lines in this function to (if possible) one single line.

```
myFiles = ['image94.jpg','image95.png','image96.jpg','movie97.mov']
suff = ('.jpg', '.png')

# Check if files are images
def checker(suff):
    imageFiles = []
    for files in myFiles:
        if files.endswith(suff):
            imageFiles.append(files)
    return imageFiles

if checker(suff): print checker(suff)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a conditional list comprehension:

```
[filename for filename in myFiles if filename.endswith(suff)]
```

Comment: amazing, just one question it prints `[]` if empty?

Comment: @Rizzit: `print([])` would do that but `bool([]) == False` so you keep your `if` in place, it shouldn't print nothing

Answer (score 0):

Try the magic of lambdas..

```
f = lambda suff,l:filter(lambda x: '.'+x.split('.')[-1] in suff,l)
```

To use it call it like

```
f(suff,myFiles)
```